# null parameters from angular

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to send parameters from my angular app using httpRequest.
I am getting back Null to my backend server.
I have checked with Postman and Fiddler both work with a json Object.
I have tried changing from Post to Get.
I am using Java RestAPI for the backend with apache Tomcat as the server.

**This is my Service for login:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
private loginURL='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/loginpage/login'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

 public login(loginDetailes:LoginDetailes):Observable<LoginDetailes>{
  return this.http.post<LoginDetailes>(this.loginURL,loginDetailes,{withCredentials:true})
 } 
}
```

**This is my Login Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginDetailes } from 'src/app/Entities/LoginDetailes';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/services/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
public loggedin:boolean;
public loggedClient:string;
public errormessage:string;
public loginDetailes = new LoginDetailes();
  constructor(private loginservice:LoginService,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.loggedin=false;
  }
public onLogin():void{
  const observable=this.loginservice.login(this.loginDetailes);
  observable.subscribe((returnedLoginDetailes:LoginDetailes)=>{
    alert("Login Aquired");
    this.loggedin=true;

  if(this.loginDetailes.clientType=="ADMIN"){
    this.router.navigate(['/crtComp']);
  }
  else if(this.loginDetailes.clientType=="COMPANY"){
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
  else if(this.loginDetailes.clientType=="CUSTOMER"){
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }else{
    alert("Wrong Login Detailes");  
  }

  }, err => {
  this.errormessage=err.console.error("Wrong Detailes please Check Again!");
  alert(this.errormessage);
}
  )}}
```

**This is the login Entity :**

```
export class LoginDetailes{
    public name:string
    public password:string
    public clientType:string
    constructor(){
    }
}
```

I have tried ngModel but that didn't fix the problem.
I have tried changing my backend from Post to Get.
The problem happends only in the angular App. I can send parameters with fiddler and Postman without problem.

Comment: dont know why it got into java ill edit this out.

Comment: It seems I are passing blank login details from your component to service

Comment: @MukulSharma can you elaborate on this? im quite new to angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the answer was not in the component or the service.
the problem was in the HTML i was missing the ngModel two way data binding so my App was sending null's.